# Variable me devuelve nil terminando una funcion

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

A la hora de querer agregar datos a un array, en la función me muestra que se agregan los elementos, pero a la hora de que el tableView despliegue lo que contiene el array, despliega que no contiene nada, qué puede ser la falla?

```
func descargarImagenes (secciones:String) {

        print(secciones, "En descargar Imagenes")
        //datosSeccion.seccion = secciones
        print("El valor de la clase datosSeccion de seccion es: \(datosSeccion.seccion)")

        let referenceImage = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(restauranteSeleccionado!)/secciones/\(secciones)/\(secciones).jpg")

        referenceImage.getData(maxSize: 1 * 2000 * 2000) { (data, error) in

            if let error = error {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                print("ERROR AQUI: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {

                let imagen = UIImage(data: data!)

                let seccion = cellDatos(textoSeccion: secciones, imagenSeccion: imagen!)
                //self.datosSeccion.arrayCellData.append(seccion)
                self.datosSeccion.arrayCellData.append(seccion)

                print("Se puso la imagen wiiiii")
                print(seccion.textoSeccion)
                print(seccion.imagenSeccion)
                print(self.datosSeccion.arrayCellData.count)

            }

        }


    }

extension SeccionesVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    //MARK: - Funciones para TableView

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datosSeccion.arrayCellData.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let seccionChingona = datosSeccion.arrayCellData[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableViewSecciones.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSeccion") as! SeccionTVCell

        cell.setSeccion(seccion: seccionChingona)

        return cell

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 325
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te falta avisar al Tableview de que tiene nueva información:

añade un `reloadData()` después de setear las nuevas imágenes que ha descargado:

```
...
self.datosSeccion.arrayCellData.append(seccion)
self.tableViewSecciones.reloadData()
```